# How to delete the very last frame of a video using ffmpeg / mencoder / transcode or any other?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, script, command-line

I am trying to delete the very last frame of a video using ffmpeg / mencoder / transcode / or any other free linux application.

Here is what I have so far, and it's only extracting it, it's not deleting it from the actual video file.

```
#!/bin/bash

fn="$1"
of=${fn%.*}.jpg

lf=`ffprobe -show_streams "$fn" 2> /dev/null | awk -F= '/^nb_frames/ { print $2-1 }'`
rm -f "$of"
ffmpeg -i "$fn" -vf "select='eq(n,$lf)'" -vframes 1 "$of" 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line, which attempts to get the number of frames does not work for me. For whatever reason my test files report 'N/A' rather than a number. But since it worked for you, you were almost done.

If you know that you want to remove frame number `$lf`, you can just do the following:

```
let frames=$lf-1
ffmpeg -i "$fn" -frames:v $frames -c:v copy -c:a copy "$of"
```